# How to create a list of icons on a vertical arc in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to implement this particular dribbble design in Flutter. Any hints on how to proceed?

[image: dribbble design in Flutter]

Comment: you can calculate some maths and use Positioned in stack.

Comment: but actually [Flow](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flow-class.html) will give you much better UX - check the sample provided in the documentation

Comment: @pskink Can we need to apply maths for dx and dy translations ?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is similar to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51407683/7924072

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya of course you have to apply basic [circle math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) (first class of secondary school as i remember correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pskink Suggested, I have tried `Flow` widget. Let me know If anyone have better idea.

**FlowMenu Statefulwidget**

```
class FlowMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FlowMenuState createState() => _FlowMenuState();
}

class _FlowMenuState extends State<FlowMenu>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController menuAnimation;
  IconData lastTapped = Icons.notifications;

  void _updateMenu(IconData icon) {
    if (icon != Icons.menu) setState(() => lastTapped = icon);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    menuAnimation = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      vsync: this,
    );
    menuAnimation.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  Widget flowMenuItem(MenuData menuData) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        RawMaterialButton(
          fillColor:
              lastTapped == menuData.iconData ? Colors.amber[700] : Colors.blue,
          splashColor: Colors.amber[100],
          shape: CircleBorder(),
          onPressed: () {
            _updateMenu(menuData.iconData);
            menuAnimation.status == AnimationStatus.completed
                ? menuAnimation.reverse()
                : menuAnimation.forward();
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Icon(
              menuData.iconData,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 45.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Transform.scale(
          scale: menuAnimation.value,
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: menuAnimation.value,
            child: Text(menuData.text),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Flow(
            delegate: FlowMenuDelegate(menuAnimation: menuAnimation),
            children: menuItems
                .map<Widget>((MenuData menuData) => flowMenuItem(menuData))
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**FlowMenuDelegate - for repaint childrens(menu)**

```
class FlowMenuDelegate extends FlowDelegate {
  FlowMenuDelegate({this.menuAnimation}) : super(repaint: menuAnimation);

  final Animation<double> menuAnimation;

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FlowMenuDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return menuAnimation != oldDelegate.menuAnimation;
  }

  @override
  void paintChildren(FlowPaintingContext context) {
    double dx = 0.0, dy = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < context.childCount; ++i) {
      // dx = context.getChildSize(i).width * i;
      dx = 200.0 * cos(menuItems[i].angle * (pi / 180));
      dy = 200.0 * sin(menuItems[i].angle * (pi / 180));
      context.paintChild(
        i,
        transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
          dx * menuAnimation.value,
          dy * menuAnimation.value,
          0,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**Test Data**

```
final List<MenuData> menuItems = <MenuData>[
  MenuData(iconData: Icons.home, text: "Home", angle: -60),
  MenuData(iconData: Icons.new_releases, text: "Release", angle: -30),
  MenuData(iconData: Icons.notifications, text: "Notification", angle: 0),
  MenuData(iconData: Icons.settings, text: "Settings", angle: 30),
  MenuData(iconData: Icons.menu, text: "Menu", angle: 60),
];
```

Comment: i would not use `menuAnimation.value` for multiplying `dx` and `dy` but rather for multiplying the angle, that way your items will move over the circle

Comment: what you mean by that?

Comment: animate from clicked button position to circle position.

Comment: sorry I have no idea what you mean

Comment: like [this Animation](https://reactnativeexample.com/content/images/2017/08/react-native-circular-action-menu.gif).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202218/discussion-between-abhay-koradiya-and-pskink).

Comment: I was able to get this to working with the above code, only change i did is to add some offset to x and y